# React Native runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing value, not reflected in github actions

Tags: xcode, react-native, github-actions, ad-hoc-distribution, xcode-archive

I have disabled xcode build phase `Bundle React Native code and images`, but setting `runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 1`:

```
00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC /* Bundle React Native code and images */ = {
        isa = PBXShellScriptBuildPhase;
        buildActionMask = 8;
        files = (
        );
        inputPaths = (
        );
        name = "Bundle React Native code and images";
        outputPaths = (
        );
        runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing = 1;
        shellPath = /bin/sh;
        shellScript = "set -e\n\nexport NODE_BINARY=/usr/local/bin/node\n../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh\n";
    };
```

Because the build phase was failing when I was archiving app on local. After the setting above, local archive passed successfully.

But, now when I'm trying to archive using github actions `yukiarrr/ios-build-action@v1.5.0`, it fails with the same error like it was failing on local before updating  `runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing` setting.

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pixidium-eyrioodbvepenugnskmjmdofbdnt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Pixidium/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pixidium.build/Release-iphoneos/Pixidium.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target 'Pixidium' from project 'Pixidium')
```

I cannot understand why this setting value doesn't reflect in CI and it works on local.

Any ideas?